# I'm getting an error of Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, object

I am creating a simple quiz app but I am stuck at making an object constructor 
the error is Uncaught TypeError: Question.pushQuestion is not a function

```
function Question(question){
    this.question = [];
}

Question.prototype.pushQuestion = function(question){
    this.question.push(question);
}

var question1 = Question("is 1 = 1 ?");
Question.pushQuestion(question1);//error
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do here. Do you expect each `Question` instance to have its own list of questions? Or do you expect there to only one master list of questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var question1 = new Question("is 1 = 1 ?");
```

You've missed the `new` keyword.

Also, here you create instance of your object:

```
var question1 = Question("is 1 = 1 ?");
```

So, you should use `question1` in order to access any method from prototype chain, e.g.

`question1.pushQuestion('How are you doing?');`

Answer (score 1):

When you define a function on an object prototype, you can invoke it by calling the function on a new-ed up instance of that object.

```
function Question(question){
    this.question = [];
}

Question.prototype.pushQuestion = function(question){
    this.question.push(question);
}

var question1 = new Question("is 1 = 1 ?");
question1.pushQuestion(question1);
```

What are you trying to achieve? Because I'm pretty sure you don't want to push the question itself into `question.list`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to generate a list of questions. I would approach like this:

```
function QuestionList() {
    this.questions = [];
    this.counter = 0;
}

QuestionList.prototype.pushQuestion = function (question) {
    this.questions.push(question);
}

var questionList = new QuestionList();

questionList.pushQuestion("is 1 = 1 ?");
questionList.pushQuestion("is 1 = 2 ?");

questionList.questions // [ "is 1 = 1 ?", "is 1 = 2 ?" ]
```

You can then write a new method to get the next question in the list:

```
QuestionList.prototype.getNextQuestion = function (question) {
    return this.questions[this.counter++];
}

questionList.getNextQuestion(); // "is 1 = 1 ?"
questionList.getNextQuestion(); // "is 1 = 2 ?"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g5crf1L7/1/)